# Give the Taylor series for the following $f(z)$; also, find $f^{(100)}(0)$

Tags: complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

$$e^{3z}$$

I'm not sure how to approach this complex number problem. I know that

$$1+3 x+\frac{9 x^2}{2}+\frac{9 x^3}{2}+\frac{27 x^4}{8}+\cdots$$

is true for $e^{3x}$, but how does this apply to complex numbers? Do I treat $z$ as a variable? If that's the case, then the Taylor series for my problem is exactly the same as the expansion I wrote above, only with a $z$ instead of and $x$. It doesn't feel like that's what I'm supposed to be learning here.

Comment: I'm guessing that where you wrote f(100)(0) you meant $f^{(100)}(0)$, and I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, the Taylor series for $e^z$ is indeed $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ for complex valued $z$.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat For the 100th derivative, do you know which term in the taylor expansion becomes a constant after deriving the series 100 times?

Comment: @imranfat I guess $e^{3z}$ stays constant

Comment: No, When taking a derivative 100 times, then the first term you get to be constant is the term that carries a 100 in the exponent of your series....

Comment: @imranfat so would that be $(3z-a)$? I'm trying to understand your concept. I'm looking at [the formula for Taylor series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html).

Comment: The way how I read it is that you would have to replace the $z$ by $3x$ in the summation formula of $y=e^{3x}$ This gives the sum of $\frac{3^nx^n}{n!}$ starting from n=0 When you take the 100th derivative of this term, how would that look like? The first term would be a constant, which is $3^{100}$ (the n! cancels) followed by x-terms. What happens if $x=0$?

Answer (score 1):

This exercise on its own doesn't teach you much--just a little about the algebra of manipulating power series, which as you mentioned, is the same whether the variable is real or complex.

What you'll learn as you continue in complex analysis is that complex-differentiable functions have much nicer properties with respect to their power series than real-differentiable functions do. For example, if I have a complex differentiable function $f$, and I find its power series, I am guaranteed that it will converge until I reach a point where the function is not defined (for instance, a point where the function goes to infinity in absolute value). This is definitely not true for real-valued functions--for example, $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is defined for all $x$ but its power series at zero has a finite radius of convergence.

Comment: So no need to interpret $z$ as $x+iy$?